# Can lftp get take in a variable name?

Tags: variable, lftp

I want to have a script that uses lftp to download a zip file with a variable name. Currently I have the following:

```
open server
user user pass
set ssl:verify-certificate no
ls -ltA1 | grep .zip$ | head -n 1
```

Executing this along side `lsftp -f` returns just the file name I need. Theoretically now I would run

```
file="$(lftp -f get_list)"
lftp -u user:pass server:21 -e "get ${file}; bye"
```

and it should work right? When doing this the lftp command ends up in a reconnect loop. So I tried to do the variable name thing in the first block of code but have no idea how to set the output of that `ls` command to work with the `get` command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
lftp -u user:pass server -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; get ${file}; bye"
```